# Convert a non-integer in base d to a number in base 10 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, radix

I have a column vector `t` of dimension `nx1` in Matlab reporting the digits after the comma of a number A in base `d`. I want to convert it in a `1x1` double reporting the number A in base `10`. I am interested in the cases `d=2` and `d=3`.

Example

```
%d=3
t=[0 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 0]'; %that is A=0.020220020 in base 3
%d=2
t=[0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]'; %that is A=0.011100010 in base 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to deal with formats: I start with t that is a double and I want to get a double.

Comment: And base2dec is for integers, right? Here I have a non-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = base2dec(char(t(:).'+'0'), d) / d^numel(t);
```

This works as follows:

1. Treat the digits as if they were to the *left* of the decimal mark, thus defining an *integer* in base `d`. That way you can use [`base2dec`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/base2dec.html) for the conversion (note that the input to this function needs to be `char`).
2. Divide by the appropriate power of `d` to take into account that the input digits actually are to the *right* of the decimal mark.

For example, given

```
t = [0 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 0]';
d = 3;
```

the result is

```
A =
   0.255448864502362
```